# Django low level cache views

Tags: python, django, caching, django-views, low-level

I have an index view which validates a form containing various data. Even though the thankyou.html page doesn't have complex calculations to kill the server, I would like to render a slightly different html page if thankyou.html is already low level cached. To tell you the truth, I don't know what key to pass it...

Here is the code:

```py
def index(request):

    form = UserForm()
    message = 'Incorrect data!'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                User.objects.get(code=form.cleaned_data['code'])

            except (KeyError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
                u = User(lastname=form.cleaned_data['lastname'],
                        surname=form.cleaned_data['surname'],
                        address=form.cleaned_data['address'],
                        email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                        phone=form.cleaned_data['phone'],
                        code=form.cleaned_data['code'],
                    )

                u.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
                #return redirect('thankyou')

    return render_to_response('index.html',{'message': message,'form' : form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I guess this is the way I should low level cache it:

```py
                if form.is_valid():
                    key = ???
                    cached_html = cache.get (key)
                    try:
                        User.objects.get(code=form.cleaned_data['code'])

                    except (KeyError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
                        u = User(lastname=form.cleaned_data['lastname'],
                        surname=form.cleaned_data['surname'],
                        address=form.cleaned_data['address'],
                        email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                        phone=form.cleaned_data['phone'],
                        code=form.cleaned_data['code'],
                    )               
                        u.save()

                        if not cached_html:

                            cached_html = render_to_response('ty.html',{ },
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))

                            cache.set(key, cached_html, time_until_midnight())

                        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
                        #return redirect('thankyou')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, in this case, you should use string `('thankyou' + form.cleaned_data['code'])` as key.